# MAUI msal login issue on iOS

Tags: c#, ios, maui, azure-ad-msal

I have a MAUI application with SSO login, and it's working perfectly on android. But in iOS getting the below error while login.
[image]

Here is my Entitlement.plist, and added this on custom entitlement field on the bundle signing option.

```
 <plist version="1.0">
   <dict>       
    <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
     <array>
       <string>$(AppIdentifierPrefix)com.microsoft.adalcache</string>
     </array>
    </dict>
  </plist
```

Comment: did you follow the link in the error message?  It walks you through the config and has a section that specifically addresses this error message

Comment: @Jason I did follow that link, and I have everything it suggests. And yet I have this error.

Comment: @DavidShochet if you get any solution , please share it here. I'm stuck on this.

Comment: @Xamarin I posted my answer.

Comment: I tried this, but didn't work on simulator on real device entitlement with "com.microsoft.adalcache" is working.

Comment: @Xamarin I guess you have something different, as I tried only on a real device, and it works only with our bundle ID. Maybe it will help somebody else...

Answer (score 0):

Some Microsoft people suggested me to replace com.microsoft.adalcache in Entitlements.plist and in WithIosKeychainSecurityGroup() with our bundle identifier (see CFBundleIdentifier in Info.plist).

And now it works. I still don't know what is wrong with com.microsoft.adalcache.